# Creating HTTP code 500 alert using Datadog monitoring multiple systems in the same alert

Tags: alert, monitoring, outliers, datadog, anomaly-detection

So our server consists of users, and each user may select one of the 3rd party services we provide to communicate with.

Each 3rd party service has a different size of user population communicating with it through our system (and increasing):

- Service (A) might has 30k users
- Service (B) has 5k
- Service (C) has 100k

We want to create an alert whenever any of these services are down (meaning monitoring 500s).

We send a metric from a central networking point in our code when 500 occurs, includes the `url` of the service as a tag.

A couple of constraints:

1. We prefer to create just one monitor that catches all and reports each service individually (so if service A and B are down, we get 2 alerts). We don't want to create multiple monitors for the same purpose to monitor different services (and maybe create a composite monitor) because the services we communicate with might increase in the future.
2. We don't want to explicitly set a `threshold` on the number of 500s on the single monitor we create, above which the monitor sends an alert, because each service has a different size of user population, so 10 occurrences in 10 mins of 500 for Service (C) (has 100k) shouldn't be considered as service down, compared to Service (B) (has 5k).

I thought of using Outlier or Anomaly monitors but we're trying to figure out the best configuration for it to avoid any false positives. So changing the Outlier algorithm between `DBSCAN` and `MAD` sometimes yield nothing and changing the tolerance yields false positives.

This is with `DBSCAN`, tolerance 3.0 - the big spike is not detected
[image]

tolerances till 1.0 detects nothing, but 0.5 detects everything, which might be false positives
[image]

Same behavior with `MAD` algorithms , there's no specific tolerance to catch the correct values

Any recommendations regarding the configuration above is welcome, or even if you think there should be a different kind of a monitor used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could attach a service tag to the metrics and create a `Multi Alert` monitor to alert for each service that meets the threshold.

> A Multi Alert monitor triggers individual notifications for each entity in a monitor that meets the alert threshold.
> For example, when setting up a monitor to notify you if the P99 latency, aggregated by service, exceeds a certain threshold, you would receive a separate alert for each individual service whose P99 latency exceeded the alert threshold.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/configuration/?tab=thresholdalert#alert-grouping

2. If you have the "number of users per service" count in Datadog as a metric, you could normalize the error count relative to the user count and setup thresholds based on that value.
   **Example**:
   Service A(100 users) - 10 errors/100 users = 0.1.
   Service B(2000 users) - 10 errors/2000 users = 0.005.
   So, if you set a threshold of >= 0.1, Service A would alert when there are 10 or more errors and service B would alert only when there are 200 or more errors.

Comment: That's exactly the route I took eventually.